# Apache will not start

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

As title:

Added a ssl certificate and key into apaches folders ssl and ssl/private (etc/apache2/ssl)

Running apache -config test results in an error saying the key file is in the private folder is missing or empty running as sudo the OK is outputted no error..

Run to start the apache service I get the error exit code 1 please see error logs to that effect

On apache error log shows the ssl key and certificate error ( these certificates are from my domain supplier) basically cut and paste he contents of those into ssl/ssl.crt and ssl/private/key.key

Pointed the config to them correctly. Running as sudo I get an OK on the apache test config command

Come to start apache service no reason in journal-xe for failure just exit code 1

Repeated the command a few times at 10 min intervals to see logs nothing added extra at the time stamps I checked in the logs.

Any other points on where to look? Thanks

*Edited* to post logs

```
Jan 14 14:32:19 thanatos systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 14 14:32:19 thanatos apachectl[2118]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to supp>
Jan 14 14:32:19 thanatos apachectl[2095]: Action 'start' failed.
Jan 14 14:32:19 thanatos apachectl[2095]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 14 14:32:19 thanatos systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 14 14:32:19 thanatos systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 14 14:32:19 thanatos systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Apache error log:

```
[Thu Jan 13 14:37:56.373695 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 739] AH02565: Certificate and private key thanatos.wh-computers.co.uk:443:0 from /etc/ssl/private/sslcert.crt and /etc/ssl/private/sslkey.key do not match
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Comment: I'm not seeing *specific* errors from Apache in your question. Could you [edit] your post to include what Apache is telling you? Copy/paste is best. The `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file would have the most accurate information about *why* it's not starting ... unless you're using XAMPP ...

Comment: Edit Post to reflect changes, thanks for taking time to reply

Comment: You may want to confirm the copy/paste. If you used Windows for the task, there’s probable some garbage Unicode hidden in the file that’s messing up the validation 

Comment: Thanks for formatting the post correctly, I will confirm the copy/paste and report back

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1076853/how-to-fix-ah02565-certificate-and-private-key-do-not-match

Comment: @garethTheRed, thanks for replying I checked them earlier and they match 100% no windows garbage at all copied over

Comment: Did you compare modulus as one of the answers suggested?

Comment: Thanks for all thats commented, @garethTheRed modulus was checked and didnt(!) match on the 2nd attempt of getting a key and certs from the domain supplier. I revoked certificate and waited 48 hours and restarted the process and it now works Thanks